# MySQL: Select count of returning vs. new rows in MySQL with period

Tags: mysql

I have database table in MySQL, which consist of the following fields:

- id
- user_id
- timestamp

The table is a simple log of visitors. I am trying to get the following numbers in one query:

- Distinct user_id's for a specific time period (30 days)
- Amount of these user_id's, which already exist in the table, regardless of time period

I have been able to do it within the period with this simple query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS 'count_distinct',
    COUNT(user_id) AS 'count_all'
FROM
    table
WHERE
    timestamp BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE();
```

Running this query gives me the count of distinct user_id's and the count of all user_id's within the time period. I can then apply the math myself to get the count of new vs. returning visitors - for that period. What I am trying to figure out is how many distinct user_id's, who visited within 30 days, who has also visited at any previous point in time.

I hope you can help me solve this.